# unable to access the application deployed on kubernetes cluster using kubernetes playground

Tags: kubernetes

I have a 3 node cluster created on kubernetes playground

The 3 nodes as seen on the UI are :

```
192.168.0.13 : Master
192.168.0.12 : worker
192.168.0.11 : worker
```

I have a front end app connected to backend mysql.

The deployment and service definition for front end is as below.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: springboot-app
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 8080
  selector:
    app: springboot-app
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: springboot-app
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: springboot-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: springboot-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: chinmayeepdas/springbootapp:1.0
        name: springboot-app
        env:
        - name: DATABASE_HOST
          value: demo-mysql
        - name: DATABASE_NAME
          value: chinmayee
        - name: DATABASE_USER
          value: root
        - name: DATABASE_PASSWORD
          value: root
        - name: DATABASE_PORT
          value: "3306"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: app-port
```

My PODs for UI and backend are up and running.

```
[node1 ~]$ kubectl describe service springboot-app
Name:                     springboot-app
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=springboot-app
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.96.187.226
Port:                     <unset>  8080/TCP
TargetPort:               8080/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30373/TCP
Endpoints:                10.32.0.2:8080,10.32.0.3:8080,10.40.0.3:8080
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Now when i do,

http://192.168.0.12:30373/employee/getAll

I dont see any result. I get This site can’t be reached

What IP address i have to give in the URL?

Comment: Have you tried to reach your service on endpoints from another non-cluster pod using telnet or curl?

Answer (score 0):

try this solution

```
kubectl proxy --address 0.0.0.0
```

Then access it as http://localhost:30373/employee/getAll

or maybe:

http://localhost:8080/employee/getAll

let me know if this fixes the access issue and which one works.